# How to move all lines containing at least one matching phrase to the end of the file?

Tags: bash, sorting

How can I move all of the lines in a file which contain at least one matching phrase to the end of the file? E.g., file:

```
Do you like to read books?
Yes, do you like to watch movies?
No, but the fish does.
```

If the search phrases were "book" and "movie", then the first two lines above would move to the end of the file, e.g.:

```
No, but the fish does.
Do you like to read books?
Yes, do you like to watch movies?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
grep "match1|match2" input.txt > tmp1
grep -v "match1|match2" input.txt > tmp2
cat tmp2 tmp1 > output.txt
rm tmp1 tmp2
```

Or, as pointed by Kevin, without using temporary files:

```
cat <(grep "match1|match2" input.txt) <(grep -v "match1|match2" input.txt) > output.txt
```

Comment: You can skip the temp files: `cat <(grep -v match) <(grep match)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty way:

```
(grep -v -e movie -e book file; grep -e movie -e book file) >newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another way in full bash:

```
#!/bin/bash -
declare -a HEAD
declare -a BOTTOM

while read -r line
do
        case "$line" in
                *book*|*movie*)
                        BOTTOM[${#BOTTOM[*]}]="${line}";
                        ;;
                *)
                        HEAD[${#HEAD[*]}]="${line}";
                ;;
        esac    # --- end of case ---
done < "$1"

for i in "${HEAD[@]}" "${BOTTOM[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```